# Использование F# функций из C#

Tags: c#, .net, f#

В проекте на C# понадобилось использовать F# функцию (`FSharpFunc`). Но при попытке это сделать получаю ошибку компиляции

> error CS1660: Не удается преобразовать лямбда-выражение к типу
>   "FSharpFunc <_, _>", так как он не является типом делегата.

MCVE

Класс User

```
class User
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Тестовые данные

```
var users = new List<User>
{
    new User { Age = 15 },
    new User { Age = 21 },
    new User { Age = 32 },
    new User { Age = 35 },
    new User { Age = 23 }
};
```

Попытка вызова функции из модуля Seq

```
User max = SeqModule.MaxBy<User, int>(x => x.Age, users);
```

Comment: на самом деле тут проблема только в том, что компилятор не может определить `x => x.Age` - это Expression или готовый делегат. Тут кстати был конкретно об этом вопрос и вроде даже с ответом.

Comment: @Grundy не буду спорить, так как точно не знаю. Поищите ссылку, чтобы был связанный вопрос?

Comment: Ну это легко проверить, передав вместо лямбды делегат `delegate(User x) { return x.Age; }` У меня, к сожалению, нет компилятора под рукой.

Comment: @Андрей нет, такой вариант не будет компилироваться

Comment: @FoggyFinder, а, да, тут проблема в том, что `FSharpFunc` не является делегатом. Это другая проблема

Comment: @Grundy ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, на данный момент, для того, чтобы вызвать F# функцию нужно явно использовать конвертер:

```
User max1 = SeqModule.MaxBy(FSharpFunc<User, int>.FromConverter(x => x.Age), users);
```

или совсем немного более короткий способ

```
User max2 = SeqModule.MaxBy<User, int>((Converter<User, int>)(x => x.Age), users);
```